# Is there a way we can change the /nifi in the URL?

Tags: url, localhost, apache-nifi

When we launch the NiFi on localhost, it's running on

```
http://localhost:8080/nifi/
```

I want to change that URL to

```
http://localhost:8080/customword/
```

Comment: why? i mean you can change 8080 to something, but why base-url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported. However, you could always run a proxy in front of NiFi that is listening on any host/port/context-path that you want.

Comment: Not possible even without making changes in Java?

Comment: NiFi is comprised of a number of web applications all hosted in an embedded Jetty server. The content path of each of those applications is well defined and used throughout the application. If your attempting to change this it would be easy to miss one of these paths. If you're attempting to change the context path, I would suggest running a proxy in front of NiFi.